# Laravel 5 on Heroku file_put_contents permission issue

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I deployed my Laravel 5 app (empty initial app) to Heroku using Github repository and it keeps producing exception

`production.ERROR: ErrorException: file_put_contents(/8a232580639f5a7a06b1d497d0825c281c17c91d.php): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:7198`

Why would it even try to create a file in the root `/` directory?

The interesting thing is if I create a new Laravel application and deploy it using Heroku's Git (vs Github repo) it works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `storage/` path is not ignored. Instead of ignoring the whole `storage/` path, replace it with the following in your .gitignore. This can be improved on what are the files and directories that will be created under storage, I haven't much done laravel/lumen in a while so I'm not so sure. But this are the basic ones.

`storage/app/*.php
storage/framework/*/*.php`